# What is the reason & solution of unexpected pause in Abaqus batch run?

Tags: batch-file, abaqus

Occasionally, I encountered an unexpected pause in the Abaqus batch run. The prompt is expected to run all the jobs from the beginning to the end but it will pause at "pre.exe" or "standard.exe" sometimes.
The batch file is like this:

```
abq6141 job=Job-1 cpus=1 interactive
abq6141 job=Job-2 cpus=1 interactive
abq6141 job=Job-3 cpus=1 interactive
```

With hundreds or thousands of jobs to run, I should check the prompt from time to time and make the jobs continue to run. The unexpected pause is annoying.

Comment: It's an `.exe` @Mofi, _it isn't a batch file with a missing `.cmd` or `.bat` extension, (so is very likely using the wrong command `Call` when running it)!_

Comment: Do you have job files leftover from previous runs? If Abaqus detects existing files it will prompt if you want to overwrite them. I don't think there is a command line flag to turn the prompt off, but you can add `ask_delete=OFF` to abaqus_v6.env to turn it off.

Comment: @brady. The Job file (.inp) and the batch file (.bat) was put in a totally new folder. There is no problem of "overwrite". Anyway, thanks for your advice of "ask_delete=OFF".

Comment: I've had this happen too. Just one possible reason: mouse-clicking in the cmd window.